# Fitting 3 subplots on the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 3 subplots on the same figure and for some reason the code I have is not working. The first two appear on the same figure, but the last one doesn't. Can someone help me out:

```
fig = plt.figure(0, figsize = (12,10))

fig.add_subplot(221)
bike_gender.plot(kind='bar',title='Trip Duration by Gender', figsize= (9,7))
bar_plot.set_ylabel('Trip duration')
bar_plot.set_xlabel('Gender')
bar_plot.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Men', 'Women', 'Unknown'])
bar_plot.text (0, 400000, 'Men = 647,466', bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
bar_plot.text (1, 400000, 'Women = 202,136', bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
bar_plot.text (2, 400000, 'Unknown = 119,240', bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))

fig.add_subplot(222)
labels = 'Subscriber \n (849,778)', 'Customer \n (119,064)'
pie_chart = bike_user.plot(kind='pie', title= 'Breakdown of usertype', labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', figsize=(9,7))

fig.add_subplot(212)
frequencies.plot(kind='bar',color=['blue','yellow','green'], figsize=(12, 4), stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to use [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)

ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:])

data.plot(ax = ax1)
data.plot(ax = ax2)
data.plot(ax = ax3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The last plot should actually appears on the figure, but behind the second one.

It's because your third subplot is in a grid whose shape differs from what you already use. You first 2 plots are on a 2x2 grid (`add_subplot(22.)`) while the last one is on a 2x1 grid (`add_subplot(21.)`).

As a quick fix, you can try for your last plot:

```
fig.add_subplot(223)
```

And it should work.

However, you seems to want to make plot with pandas and display them in a specific `axes` of a `figure` with subplots. To do so you should use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(12,10))
bike_gender.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax[0], title='Trip Duration by Gender')
bike_user.plot(kind='pie', ax=ax[1], title= 'Breakdown of usertype')
frequencies.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[2], color=['blue','yellow','green'], stacked=True)
```

HTH

Comment: For some reason it is still not working; it's still showing up on two different figures. I wanted the first two to be on the top, and the third one to be underneath. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, that's odd. If you use the 4 lines I wrote you shouldn't have any problem. If you do have, please provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem.